# Secret message encrypt/decrypt ÅÄÖ

Tags: vb.net, encryption, message

I need to add this encryptdecrypt code ÄÖÅ characters, but i don't know how?
Here's my code:

```
Public Function EncryptDecryptString(ByVal inputString As String, Optional ByVal decrypt As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim sourceChars As String = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Dim resultChars As String = "36N8lkXruq94jMZInPpshR xHc2mTQb7eYai5vGWDzFdoC0wKSBt1EOgVALJfUy"

    Dim result As String
    If decrypt Then
        result = New String(inputString.Select(Function(c) sourceChars(resultChars.IndexOf(c))).ToArray())
    Else
        result = New String(inputString.Select(Function(c) resultChars(sourceChars.IndexOf(c))).ToArray())
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: You're going to have to give more information I think. I don't know what those character's codes are, but they're probably  exceeding the range you gave your program (ASCII codes 32-127?). And instead of manually mapping from source-to-result, you should make a function that generates result String. Then you could just add new characters to the sourcechars, and have it randomly assigned a character to them.

Comment: "Then you could just add new characters to the sourcechars" I tired that, failed. ÄÖÅ äöå , finnish letters

Comment: +fubz (Disclaimer: I don't know VB). Generate the source String instead of hard coding it like you have. I'm assuming your problem is that you can't type the characters in the source String? You really need to include more details.

Comment: If you want to do *real* encryption, here's a good start: [Walkthrough: Encrypting and Decrypting Strings in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current code will work (as well as it does for English characters) if you simply add the Swedish characters to **both** sourceChars and resultChars like this.

```
Dim sourceChars As String = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÅabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789äöå"
Dim resultChars As String = "äöå36N8lkXruq94jMZInPpshR xHc2mTQb7eYai5ÄÖÅvGWDzFdoC0wKSBt1EOgVALJfUy"
```

However, your code will fail if the input string contains any character that you are not expecting (for example a tab character or newline). Here is a version of the function that doesn't throw an exception on an unexpected character, but simply uses it without encrypting that character (for serious encryption, it would be better to get an exception).

```
Public Function EncryptDecryptString(ByVal inputString As String, Optional ByVal decrypt As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim sourceChars As String = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÅabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789äöå"
    Dim resultChars As String = "äöå36N8lkXruq94jMZInPpshR xHc2mTQb7eYai5ÄÖÅvGWDzFdoC0wKSBt1EOgVALJfUy"

    Dim result() As Char = inputString
    Dim inChars As String = If(decrypt, resultChars, sourceChars)
    Dim outChars As String = If(decrypt, sourceChars, resultChars)

    For i As Integer = 0 To inputString.Length - 1
        Dim pos As Integer = inChars.IndexOf(inputString(i))
        If pos >= 0 Then result(i) = outChars(pos)
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```